# responsive jquery popup for all resolutions asp net

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

i have this popup that i built with html, css and jquery that seems a litte bit off. when i test it at a 1920x1080 resolution screen, it's all fine with the width, height and everything. but as soon as i go to a smaller resolution or bigger for that matter, with the same or another web browser, the modal gets off. the buttons are outside the box, the modal seems smaller etc. how should i fix this? (iam already using % instead of px for my width and height as you will see below.)

HTML (ASPX):

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h3 class="modalHdr">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTRemove Selected Visitor" />
        </h3>
        <p>
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="TRNSLTConfirmRemoveVisitor"></asp:Label>
            "<%# Eval("VisitorFirstName") %> <%# Eval("VisitorSurName") %>"
        </p>
        <asp:Button ToolTip="TRNSLTNo" CommandName="noBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("VisitorID") %>' ID="ButtonNo" runat="server" Text="TRNSLTNo" CssClass="popupConfirm" />
        <asp:Button ToolTip="TRNSLTYes" CommandName="yesBtn" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("VisitorID") %>' ID="ButtonYes" runat="server" Text="TRNSLTYes" CssClass="popupConfirm" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    padding-top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    font-size: 13px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

    .modal-content {
        background-color: #fefefe;
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 200px;
        padding: 20px;
        border: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
        width: 27%;
        height: 18.5%;
    }

    .modalHdr {
        margin-left: -1px;
        font-size: 20px;
    }

    .popupConfirm {
        border: 1px #aaa;
        padding: 10px 82px;
        text-align: center;
        text-decoration: none;
        display: inline-block;
        font-size: 13px;
        margin: 20% 2px;
        cursor: pointer;
        background: lightgrey;
        color: black;
    }
```

JavaScript (jQuery)

```
function OpenPopup($this) {
    if ($($this).attr("disabled") === "disabled") {
        return false;
    }
    var module = $($this).parent().find("#myModal");
    module.show();
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target === module) {
            module.hide();
        }
    };

    return false;
}

jQuery.fn.center = function (parent) {
    if (parent) {
        parent = this.parent();
    } else {
        parent = window;
    }
    this.css({
        "position": "fixed",
        "top": ((($(parent).height() - this.outerHeight()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollTop() + "px"),
        "left": ((($(parent).width() - this.outerWidth()) / 2) + $(parent).scrollLeft() + "px")
    });
    return this;
}

$(window).resize(function () {
    $("#myModal").center();
});
```

Comment: try adding min-width and min-height for .modal-content. adjust them to your content - e.g   min-width:200px; min-height:100px;

Comment: could you create a post please